# Query for first two elements of a group by descending

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
FruitID | FruitDate | FruitType
  23    |  10/20/14 |   3
  32    |  10/12/14 |   3
  39    |  09/23/14 |   3
```

There are many `FruitTypes` and I want to extract a list of object models that contains the last two Fruits, for instance `{FruitID : 23, Date: 10/20}, {FruitID : 32, Date: 10/12}`

This is what I have:

```
var Output = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
              where ... some condition
              orderby f.FruitDate descending
              group f by f.FruitType in FruitGroups
              select.... new FruitModel()
              {
                   FruitID = ...
                   FruitDate = ...
                   FruitType = ...

              }).ToList();
```

I'm having trouble take the latest 2. How can I get back a list of the last 2 of each `FruitType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Output = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
              where ... some condition
              orderby f.FruitDate descending
              group f by f.FruitType in FruitGroups
              select.... new FruitModel()
              {
                   FruitID = ...
                   FruitDate = ...
                   FruitType = ...

              }).Take(2).ToList();
```

Follow-up edit

Added a missing `from` clause; this is the query:

```
var Output = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
              where ... some condition
              orderby f.FruitDate descending
              group f by f.FruitType in FruitGroups
              from t in FruitGroups
              select new FruitModel()
              {
                   FruitID = t.FruitID,
                   FruitDate = t.FruitDate
                   FruitType = t.FruitType

              }).Take(2).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, that got me started; still needed to add a new from clause just before the select. Made the edit. But thanks!! This is the answer!

Comment: Please mark this as answer if this answered your question :) If you have any other concern other than this, please do ask so

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var query = from fruit in fruitsData
                        group fruit by fruit.FruitType into g
                        select new
                        {
                            FruitType = g.Key,
                            Fruits = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.FruitDate).Take(2)
                        };
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Gvl6o).